# Force just one file as binary in GIT

Tags: git, binaryfiles

I need to add a file to a git repository, and I need the correct type of line ending.

In perforce, I would just use "`-t binary`" to force the file to binary, but I don't know how to set the file to binary in GIT.
The repository is rather large, so I don't want to make a global change.
The new file is `.html`, and I already have thousands of `.html` files whose type I don't want to change.
I don't have a choice about the name for the new file either.

So, how do I force just one file to binary in git without making global changes?

Comment: Cross-referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61845148/1315009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can record your file in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html) (that you can put in the same directory as your file):

```
yourFile.html binary
```

It is the same as:

```
yourFile.html -crlf -diff
yourFile.html -text -diff
```

This is slightly different than `core.eol` directive (in that same **[`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)** file):

```
yourFile.html eol=lf
```

That would autocorrect end of lines on `git checkout`.
You don't need that in your case: `binary` is enough.

More in "[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)".