# What is the proper way to mark a file as binary in Git Attributes?

Tags: git

The two ways I see used:

```
picture.jpg binary
```

and

```
picture.jpg -text
```

The former is not officially documented anywhere in the [gitattributes documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) from what I can see. There is some slight mention of it within the context of the `diff` attribute though (but the `diff` attribute is not used in these examples directly).

The latter one says "not text", which means it is basically binary, and no EOL normalization is performed.

Are these two functionally the same? What are the differences between the two? Specifically, the former example is the most unknown/confusing for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978627/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17883624/6309 can help

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the links. While the information is in there, the questions asked are within a different context (such as `delta` in the first link). Would be nice to see an answer to my question here that is more focused, because the answer to my specific question is rather hidden in the links you provided. There is a relevant snippet from the gitattributes docs (linked in my question): http://i.imgur.com/VyiUVZW.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), it states that marking a file as `binary` is equivalent to marking it as `-diff -merge -text`:

> The built-in macro attribute "binary" is equivalent to:
>
> [attr]binary -diff -merge -text

So, if all you want to do is avoid CRLF processing, go with `-text`; using `binary` will make diffs somewhat useless. For something like a .jpg, though, you want to use `binary`.