# How to tell git to preserve CRLF specifically for a single set of files? Mark a text file as binary?

Tags: git, email, newline, binaryfiles

I want to set some of the text files in a repo to be cloned/downloaded as binary. Ie: Bypass the CRLF settings in git and just clone byte per byte.

## Context

There are myriads of posts about CRLF in git. But normally they are about the general settings of whole projects, mainly depending on if you use Linux or Windows.

But I face a situation that never found before. I am willing to set a folder in my project with sample emails as defined by the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) which define that the end-of-line of the emails are exactly `CRLF`. It's a project related to emailing and those are going to be used for unit-testing.

If I leave the system to treat the text files as it wants, those files will download as `LF` in many cases.

I want those few files to be "forced" to be downloaded in "binary mode", so whatever the platform or settings where you are doing the `git clone`, those files will not have lost a single byte; otherwise they would break the standard.

## Question

- Is this possible?
- How can I signal **only** those those files as "binary" at the add or commit time so anyone willing to clone will have them properly cloned?
- Is there any switch for the `add` or `commit` I should use?

Comment: Cross-referenced here: https://github.com/garoose/copy-message-id/pull/5

Comment: `*.eml eol=crlf`

Comment: Cross-referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883475/1315009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed mark these files as binary in your `.gitattributes` file, but that will prevent them from being diffed and merged, which may not be what you're after.  The easier way is to specify them as having CRLF line endings, like so:

```
*.mbox eol=crlf
```

That will force those files to be written into the working tree with CRLF endings regardless of platform.  If you did, for some reason, want to mark them as binary, you could replace the `eol=crlf` with `binary`.  You might want that if your emails contained raw 8bit unencoded data, for example.

Comment: Actually the final solution was implemented here https://github.com/garoose/copy-message-id/blob/master/tests/.gitattributes and the line added a text attribute to force diffs: `*.eml text eol=crlf` as it can be seen in this github template: https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings